# Change popup rather than actual window?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to figure out how to change the popup window in a Chrome extension rather than the actual window inside of Google Chrome.

JS:

```
mkSidebar = function(which) {
    var text = "" +
        "<span " + ((which === "data") ? "id='selected'" : "") + ">Data</span>" +
        "<span " + ((which === "logic") ? "id='selected'" : "") + ">Logic</span>" +
        "<span " + ((which === "match") ? "id='selected'" : "") + ">Math</span>";
    document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = text;
};
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="mkSidebar('data');">
    <div id='sidebar'></div>
</body>
```

When I run this in JSFiddle, it works as one would expect. It fills in the HTML for the sidebar.

The problem here is when I run it as a Google Chrome extension. It just doesn't do anything.

---

My guess is that this is because it's trying to find an element which has an `id` attribute `sidebar` *inside of the Chrome window.* When I right-clicked -> inspect element inside the popup window, then directly run the javascript `mkSidebar('data');` it worked.

So how would I target the popup window rather than the Chrome window, or whatever it's doing?

(Sorry if this is a silly question.. I'm just beginning to make Chrome extensions. :P)

Comment: Is there an error thrown? [This](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2#inline_scripts) could be your issue with Manifest V2. Inline scripts are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `<body onload="mkSidebar('data');">` to the document's `DOMContentLoaded` event, or the window's `load` event since [Inline JavaScript will not be executed.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)